# SQL can't find string that is not empty

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, syntax-error

What's wrong with that line ?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM orders ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1000 WHERE TRIM(IFNULL(email,'')) <> ''";
```

Basically I want to get all emails from the sql which is NOT an empty row

This is my Error message :

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE TRIM(IFNULL(email,'')) <> ''' at line 336
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1000
```

must come after `WHERE` condition

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM 
orders WHERE 
TRIM(IFNULL(email,'')) <> '' 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1000";
```

Answer (score 2):

You `WHERE` statement needs to be after your `FROM` statement but before your `ORDER BY` ([manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/select.html)):

```
SELECT * 
FROM orders 
WHERE TRIM(IFNULL(email,'')) <> '' 
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 1000";
```